# Temporarily overriding compilation mode regexp alist: dynamic binding weirdness?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dynamic-binding, compile-mode

I'm working on a program mode, which has various different calls to assemblers, programmers and other external programs. My cunning plan was to handle all of these with the `compile` function, passing an explicit `compile-command` that depends on which program is being run.

This sort of seems to work and now I want to add specific error regexps for the different external programs. One option would be to alter `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist`, keyed on my major mode and then add my major mode to `compilation-error-regexp-alist`.

What I'd prefer to do, though, is something like the following:

```
(let ((compilation-error-regexp-alist
       (cons <my-regexp-and-numbers> compilation-error-regexp-alist))
  (compile <my-compile-command>))
```

What's weird is that this binding doesn't seem to affect the way the compilation buffer gets parsed / marked up. If I manually push `<my-regexp-and-numbers>` onto the front of `compilation-error-regexp-alist` and then call `(compilation-mode t)` on the buffer, everything gets fontified as expected (so I haven't got the regexp wrong). However, sticking the call to `(compilation-mode t)` inside a `let` form as above doesn't affect anything.

I realise this fails miserably as an easy-to-reproduce test case. If no-one has any ideas, I'll try to hack out an example, but I'm hoping that someone will go "Ah, yes! That's because  doesn't get evaluated then, but rather at " or the like...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the variable is set for the command but somehow is not passed to compile buffer.

Try your method and view the value of the variable (`C-h v`) inside the compile buffer for confirmation.

Comment: Well, it doesn't change, but I wouldn't expect it to: since Emacs uses dynamic binding, the changes to the variable disappear as soon as control passes out of the let form.

Comment: Ahah! But you're right: the parsing code gets called by font-lock, which happens later, so my changes have disappeared by then. I'll make the variable buffer-local and set it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!